# Mystery / Lucky Dip Bundled Product

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I want to create a bundled product in my Magento store that has a fixed price but the actual items are hidden from the customer and selected after order by the administrator.

For example:

#### Mystery Snack Bundle $2.99

This bundle will contain:

- 3 healthy snacks
- 2 nut snacks
- 1 treat snack

Snacks will vary depending on season and availability.

The customer would order the bundle at $2.99. Then the admin will be able to alter the order, specifying the actual items before the order goes to Picking.

Many thanks for any advice on how to accomplish this within Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to "intercept" a Magento order like this.

A simpler approach would be to create a simple product, explain in the product description/title how the product is fulfilled, and what the product contains as you have in your question.

Your back office fulfillment guys would receive a list from your admin of products to use to pack an order with this product depending on availability, season etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it was done as a simple product could the original order be altered by an admin to edit/remove product items?

Comment: You cannot edit orders after they have been placed with a default Magento store. If you google 'edit magento order' you will find commercial modules that might provide you with the functionality you want.